# MessageGroups and Exclusive Consumer using AMQPNetLite.Core 2.4.6

Tags: c#, amqp, activemq-artemis

I'm attempting to the [message grouping](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-grouping.html) and [exclusive queues](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/exclusive-queues.html) features from ActiveMQ Artemis 2.30.0 using the .NET Core AMQP NuGet package, AMQPNetLite.Core. However, the documentation for AMQPNetLite does not provide information on this topic.

I have tried to create connection with `Exclusive` as below. But in ActiveMQ Artemis web console I don't see the `Exclusive` attribute set on the queue.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = (args.Length > 0) ? args[0] :
        "amqp://admin:passw0rd@127.0.0.1:5672";
    string source = (args.Length > 1) ? args[1] : "examples";
    int count = (args.Length > 2) ? Convert.ToInt32(args[2]) : 10;

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    Address peerAddr = new Address(url);
    Amqp.Types.Fields properties= new Amqp.Types.Fields
    {
        { new Symbol("Exclusive"), true }
    };
    Connection connection = await factory.CreateAsync(peerAddr, new Open { ContainerId=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Properties=properties });
    Session           session = new Session(connection);
    ReceiverLink receiver = new ReceiverLink(session, "recv-1", source);

    while (true)
    {
        Message msg = receiver.Receive();
        receiver.Accept(msg);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: " + msg.Body.ToString());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: AMQP 1.0 and ActiveMQ Artemis 2.30.0

Comment: Can we narrow the question down to focus just on Message Grouping _or_ Exclusive Queues? At this point it looks like your only problem with with Exclusive Queues but you mention Message Grouping as well without any explanation.

Comment: @JustinBertram, In my scenario, I have an application that scales up at times, meaning multiple instances of the app start to consume the same queue. However, I don't want each instance to consume the messages; instead, I want only one instance to consume messages from the queue.

My understanding is that grouped messages require an exclusive queue to ensure that the messages are delivered to the same instance of the consumer. Am I mistaken in this understanding?

Comment: I do believe you are mistaken. Message groups and exclusive queues are rarely, if ever, used together. They are both ways to accomplish the same main goal which is the serial (i.e. strictly ordered) consumption of messages, although in slightly different ways. Message groups enforce serial message consumption by pinning a group of message to exactly one consumer. An exclusive queue does the same by allowing only a single consumer to receive messages from the queue. You need to update your question to clarify your exact use-case starting with whether you're using anycast or multicast.

Comment: @JustinBertram I apologize for the delayed response. As you mentioned in your previous comment, my understanding of message grouping and exclusive queues was incorrect. In my specific scenario, grouping alone suffices. Exclusive queue is not required. Messages from a specific group are consistently delivered to the same consumer in cases where there are multiple consumers (perhaps I should consider switching to anycast, as you suggested). If any consumer becomes inactive, the group is automatically reassigned to the active consumer.

Comment: @JustinBertram Thank you, your second comment helped me understand the difference between message grouping and an exclusive queue. However, I'm not entirely sure how to designate that comment as the accepted answer, as I'm not very experienced with Stack Overflow.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the details from my second comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclusive queues is a broker-specific feature. It's not part of the AMQP specification, and as far as I'm aware there's no extension for it so you can't configure exclusivity on the client.

As noted in the documentation, you can statically configure a queue to be exclusive, e.g.:

```xml
<address name="examples">
   <multicast>
      <queue name="exampleQueue" exclusive="true"/>
   </multicast>
</address>
```

Or you can use an `address-setting` which applies to all the queues on one or more addresses, e.g.:

```xml
<address-setting match="examples">
   <default-exclusive-queue>true</default-exclusive-queue>
</address-setting>
```

Since you're using `multicast` this is what I would recommend, although in *most* multicast use-cases there's only ever 1 consumer per queue so it's not clear why you would need this in general.

It's worth noting that message groups and exclusive queues are rarely, if ever, used together. They are both ways to accomplish the same main goal which is the serial (i.e. strictly ordered) consumption of messages, although in slightly different ways. Message groups enforce serial message consumption by pinning a group of message to exactly one consumer. An exclusive queue does the same by allowing only a single consumer to receive messages from the queue.